# How to ORDER BY a temporary table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In the following query I want to ORDER BY RAND() c table. When I put the ORDER BY RAND() inside the JOIN, query need more than 5 seconds to execute because ORDER BY runs before GROUP BY.

```
UPDATE  `backlinks` as a
    JOIN (
        SELECT  b.`id` as bid
            FROM  `backlinks` b
            WHERE  b.`googlebot_id` IS NULL
              AND  b.`used_time` IS NULL
              AND  b.`campaign_id` IN (
                SELECT  `id`  FROM  `campaigns`  WHERE  `status`=true
                                      )
            GROUP BY  b.`campaign_id` 
         ) AS c  ON a.id = c.bid
    SET a.`crawler_id` = 'test'
    limit  1;
```

Comment: Change the `IN ( SELECT ... )` into a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using  group by withou ana aggregation function
if you want just a row for each   b.`campaign_id` use some aggregation function for avoid unpredictable result for others column value and error with the most recente version of db

a proper aggregation function could avoid the needs for order by and  limit 1

and for performance you could avoid the IN clause for a subquery  and use inner join this produce the same result but is more fast

```
UPDATE `backlinks` as a
JOIN(
    SELECT min(b.`id`) as bid
    FROM `backlinks` b
    INNER JOIN (
          SELECT `id` 
          FROM `campaigns` 
          WHERE `status`=true
    ) t1 on t1.id = b.`campaign_id` 
    WHERE b.`googlebot_id` IS NULL 
    AND b.`used_time` IS NULL 
    GROUP BY b.`campaign_id`
) AS c ON a.id = c.bid
SET a.`crawler_id` = 'test'
limit 1;
```

Anyway if you are using mysql version prevoius then 5.7  you can use group by without aggreation function  .. and order by  ..  but  .. both of that have an impact on performance

```
 UPDATE `backlinks` as a
JOIN(
    SELECT b.`id` as bid
    FROM `backlinks` b
    INNER JOIN (
          SELECT `id` 
          FROM `campaigns` 
          WHERE `status`=true
    ) t1 on t1.id = b.`campaign_id` 
    WHERE b.`googlebot_id` IS NULL 
    AND b.`used_time` IS NULL 
    GROUP BY b.`campaign_id`

) AS c ON a.id = c.bid

SET a.`crawler_id` = 'test'

limit 1;
```

the uniques way for improve performance is related to the use of join instead of IN clause  and a proper index  on  table backlinks  columns campaign_id

you could try using order by rand and limit outside the subquery but inside a proper outer subquery  and join the result for the update

```
UPDATE `backlinks` as a 
INNER JOIN  (
  select  a1.id 
  from backlinks as a1
  INNER JOIN (
     SELECT b.`id` as bid
      FROM `backlinks` b
      INNER JOIN (
            SELECT `id` 
            FROM `campaigns` 
            WHERE `status`=true
      ) t1 on t1.id = b.`campaign_id` 
      WHERE b.`googlebot_id` IS NULL 
      AND b.`used_time` IS NULL 
      GROUP BY b.`campaign_id`
  )  AS c ON a1.id = c.bid 
  ORDER BY rand()  
  limit 1  
) t on t.id = a.id
```

Comment: I don't use min(b.`id`) because I want to get a random id not the min. This is the reason I am looking for a way to order by rand() c table.

Comment: anyway  the use of group by without aggrgation function allowed  only  with version of mysql  < 5.7  .. answer updated .. with some suggestion  but . your need  are not performance  "like "

Comment: ORDER by rand() inside join is very slow. This is what I ask in my question. I want to ORDER by rand() c table. That means the order will happen after group by.

Comment: Sorry for "i want" I am trying to explain what I am trying to achieve. English are not my native language.

Comment: OK  .. answer  updated ..  with another suggestion  too  .. hope this is useful